# how to send arabic sms with at-command in c#

Tags: c#, sms, arabic, at-command

How can I send Arabic SMS with the `at` command in C#? When I send Arabic messages it shows incorrect characters.

I tried using this code:

```
serialPort1.BaseStream.Flush();

            string cb = char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            this.serialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
            this.serialPort1.Write("AT+CSCA=servicecenter\r\n");//Ufone Service Center

            this.serialPort1.Write("AT+CSCS=\"" + "HEX" + "\"\r\n");
            this.serialPort1.Write("AT+CSMP=\"" + 1 + "," + 167 + "," + 0 + ","  +8+ "\"\r\n");
            this.serialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"\r\n");// message sending
            this.serialPort1.Write(textBox2.Text + cb);//message text
```

and I wrote 06450631062D06280627 in the text box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Unicode Messages (such as in Persian and Arabic) in C# using AT Commands through GSM Modem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312059/sending-unicode-messages-such-as-in-persian-and-arabic-in-c-sharp-using-at-com)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to convert your unicode strings to hexadecimal first.

From http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/ :

**Sending an Unicode SMS message**

Some modems also have the capability to send Unicode or UCS2 messages without encoding a PDU. You can send Unicode messages by only converting the Unicode data to a HEX string and send this string to the modem.

To check whether your modem supports this mode, just type the following command:
AT+CSCS=?

This commands displays the codepages supported by the modem. The modem will respond like this:
+CSCS: ("GSM","PCCP437","CUSTOM","HEX")

If this string contains "HEX" or "UCS2", Unicode seems to be supported. To specify that you will use an HEX string to send the message, set the codepage to "HEX" or "UCS2" depending on the modem response. In our example we will set the modem to "HEX" :
AT+CSCS="HEX"

Next, we have to specify the correct DCS (Data Coding Scheme) for Unicode messages, which is 0x08. We can set this value by changing the fourth parameter of the AT+CSMP command to '8':
AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8

The modem is now ready to send messages as Unicode. Now is the time to send the actual message:
AT+CMGS="+31638740161"

Replace the above phone number with your own cell phone number. The modem will respond with:
>

The only thing you have to program by yourself, is a simple routine which converts the Unicode string to an hexidecimal string like this:
مرحبا

Which is 'Hello' in arabic will be converted like this:
"06450631062D06280627"

You can send this hexidecimal string to the modem:
06450631062D06280627

After some seconds the modem will respond with the message ID of the message, indicating that the message was sent correctly:
+CMGS: 63

The message will arrive on the mobile phone shortly.

Comment: the result of AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8 is Error

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with Unicodes (Persian or Arabic messages). Please check my question and answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312059/sending-unicode-messages-such-as-in-persian-and-arabic-in-c-sharp-using-at-com). In this thread you can find out how to send Unicode messages correctly and your problem will be resolved.

First please read [this article](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/) then convert your Unicode message to Hex format and set `AT+CSCS="UCS2"`. The core of your code should look like this:

```
GSMPort.Write("AT\n");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
GSMPort.Write("AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"\n");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
GSMPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\n");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
GSMPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + destinationNumber + "\"\n");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
GSMPort.Write("06450631062D0628062706450631062D0628062706450631062D06280627" + "\x1A");
```

"06450631062D06280627" is the Hex format of "مرحبا"!

Answer (score 2):

I try to send sms in farsi language according to this article:
http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/
and it was so easy.
this is my code in c#:

```
string recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSCS=\"HEX\"", 300, "Failed to set message encoding.");
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
            //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");

            String command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + Str2Hex(PhoneNo) + "\"";
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

            command = Str2Hex(Message) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";

            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds
```

ExecCommand is a routine that send command to serial port an wait to get answer from the port.

MILAD

---

```
    public static string Str2Hex(string strMessage)
    {
        byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage);
        string strHex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
        strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "");
        return strHex;
    }
```

Comment: An error occures at this line: recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8", 300, "Failed to set message format."); Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you should use `PDU` format.

start with this [link](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/)!

Answer (score 0):

This is working to send bangla or any language and also unicode send AT Command

```
   SP.Write("AT\r");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    progressSending.Value = 40;
    SP.Write("AT+CSCS=HEX\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    progressSending.Value = 50;
    SP.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    progressSending.Value = 60;
    SP.Write("AT+CSMP=1,173,0,8\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    progressSending.Value = 70;
    SP.Write("AT+CMGS=" + here write receive number + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);           
    progressSending.Value = 80;                          
    SP.Write(Str2Hex(your stirng value) + "\x1A" + "\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    progressSending.Value = 90;
```

This is Converted string to HexaDecimal

```
public static string Str2Hex(string strMessage)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage);
    string strHex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "");
    return strHex;
 }
```