# Persian text box to hex to byte

Tags: c#, hex, arrays, persian

hi I have some text boxes  which user enters information such as first name,last name ,... .
I need to convert text boxes' text to hex and then convert the hex to bytes and send to device via rs232.

I know the sending via rs232 part and I also know how to convert text to bytes.

My problem is ,now, I should work with Persian characters in text boxes .It means the text for name in text box would for example like this "حسین".

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Why would a persian character be different from a non-persian character? Both are just a sequence of bytes. Did you test your method with persian characters?

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: I used this `var bytes = textbox.Text
                   .Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();` and It works for English strings. But when I enter Persian string in text box the values I get in bytes are not correct. I know that since when I convert back to string it gives me bunch of none since .For example for "احمد" bytes are "39,46,69,47" but the convert back is something like ".\E'"

Comment: Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky. Than improve your question by editing in code sample that causes you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can try something like that

```
  byte[] yourStrBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("your encoding").GetBytes("your str");
  string hexStr = BitConverter.ToString(yourStrBytes).Replace("-", "");
  byte[] hexStrBytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know if you want to convert a Persian or Arabic text to it's continuse unicode in order to send them to other devices via a serial port like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312059/sending-unicode-messages-such-as-in-persian-and-arabic-in-c-sharp-using-at-com) question you can use following code to reach HEX values of a Persian or Arabic letter.

```
 private string ConvertToUTF(string input_text)
    {
        string _out = String.Empty;
        char[] _chars = input_text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in _chars)
        {
            _out += ((Int16)c).ToString("X4");
        }
        return _out;
    }
```

`Useage:`

`Console.WriteLine(ConvertToUTF("سلام"));`

`Console.WriteLine(ConvertToUTF("مرحبا"));`

Provide this out put

> 0633064406270645 
>   06450631062D06280627