# how to reading Unicode Messages (such as in Persian and Arabic) in C# using AT Commands through GSM Modem?

Tags: c#, unicode, sms, gsm, at-command

i read this post to send Unicode sms message but i want to know how to read utf8 messages?

[Sending Unicode Messages (such as in Persian and Arabic) in C# using AT Commands through GSM Modem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312059/sending-unicode-messages-such-as-in-persian-and-arabic-in-c-sharp-using-at-com)

i send this command but recieved message text is something like:

```
 AT+CMGL="ALL"

  +CMGL: 1,"REC READ","97563937625","","2013/08/28 00:53:30+18"
     0041006A006D0064006A00740020
```

my commands to read sms:

```
          ExecCommand(port,"AT", 300, "No phone connected");

            ExecCommand(port,"AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"\n", 300, "No phone connected");

            ExecCommand(port,"AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");

            ExecCommand(port,"AT+CPMS=\"MT\"", 300, "Failed to select message storage.");          

            string input = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"", 5000, "Failed to read the messages.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think UTF8 is supported by GSM. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

> Short messages can be encoded using a variety of alphabets: the default GSM 7-bit alphabet, the 8-bit data alphabet, and the 16-bit UCS-2 alphabet

and from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40

> The messages in Chinese, Korean or Japanese languages must be encoded using the UTF-16 character encoding
>
> The Data Coding Scheme (TP-DCS) field contains primarily information about message encoding. GSM recognizes only 2 encodings for text messages and 1 encoding for binary messages:
>
> GSM 7 bit default alphabet (which includes using of National language shift tables as well)
>
> UCS-2
>
> 8 bit data

In the same paragraph they tell that there is a new national-based encoding (the *National language shift table*) that was introduced in 2012. Still this isn't UTF-8.

Comment: Notice that while the over the air wire format probably never is anything but 16-bit encoding, it is possible for the phone to convert to and from UTF-8 for the DTE-DCE interface if that encoding is supported in its `AT+CSCS` implementation. 27.007 defines "UTF-8" as a defined value, although it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private string decoder(string value)
    {
        Regex lettersOnly = new Regex("^[0-9]|[A-Z]$");
        if ((value.Length % 4 == 0) && lettersOnly.Match(value).Success)
        {
            string data = FromHex(value);

            return data;
        }
        else
            return value;
    }      

    public static string FromHex(string hex)
    {
        short[] raw = new short[hex.Length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToInt16(hex.Substring(i * 4, 4), 16);
        }
        string s = "";
        //wtf encoding utf32 ride ahmagh kos sher pas mide
        foreach (var item in raw)
        {
            s += char.ConvertFromUtf32(item).ToString();
        }
        return s;
    }
```