# Send SMS containting Emojis with AT Commands

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, at-command

I would like to send an SMS containing Emojis from my GSM Modem with AT Commands.

However, no matter which encoding I try, it never works (`Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`, `Encoding.Unicode` or `Default`) make the SMS unreadable.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
// [..]
// send message with UCS2
command = "AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13);
send(command);   

// [..]
// convert my message (string from a WPF TextBox) to a unicode hex-string
byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(message);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "");

// send the converted string
command = hexString  + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
send(command);
// [..]
```

The SMS successfully reaches its destination but the message is just some **unreadable stuff**.

Is this even possible to do? My GSM Modem would also support "HEX" as encoding.

**Update:**
It kinda works if i replace this line:

```
command = hexString  + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
```

With this:

```
command = "80 " + hexString + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
```

But then i get this 㣩 letter at the start of the message...

Comment: UCS-2 is unable to encode character outside the basic plane, such as emojis. Please edit your question to demonstrate/verify that encoding `"\N{NAUSEATED FACE}"` (U+1F922) into UTF-16BE results in the octets 0xd8 0x3e 0xdd 0x22 and that there is no byte-order mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your modem uses the correct data coding scheme for the SMS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15312611/306914) and

1. Set the modem to text mode using `AT+CMGF=1`
2. Set the coding scheme to `"UCS2"` using `AT+CSCS="UCS2"`
3. Send `AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8` to the modem.
4. Now in UCS2 mode, the modem needs the recipient number in UCS2 form as well, i.e. for `+123456890` send
   `AT+CGMS="002B003100320033003400350036003800390030",145` (145 is type-of-address for numbers with country code, use `129` otherwise.
5. The modem should respond with a `>`  prompt. Then, send the message in the right encoding i.e. sending the message as what I would describe as an ASCII hex sequence of UCS2/UTF-16 bytes, i.e. encoding the string to UTF-16BE, then taking each byte and formatting it as ASCII HEX characters, i.e.  which is `U+1F408` becomes `D83DDC08` that is sent to the modem, `012ABC` becomes `003000310032 004100420043`.