# Send unicode sms with java

Tags: java, sms, gsm

I send SMS via GSM device, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361225/6250402

It can send normal SMS, I try to send a Unicode text but It auto-convert to ASCII: `VD¥n ba:#n D_a:?n: TBM01`

Lib:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neuronrobotics</groupId>
    <artifactId>nrjavaserial</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My code:

```java
CommPortIdentifier portId = "I get CommPort match name";
SerialPort serialPort = portId.open("name", 2000);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
this.outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

// each command function
private void send(String cmd) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //
    outputStream.flush();
}

// this sends message method

 send("AT+CMGS=" + '"' + phone + '"' + "\r\n");
 send(message + '\032');
```

Did I have the wrong config?

Any code to send SMS via GSM for java is a good answer.

**Result** I missing `AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15312611/6250402, to more info, look https://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/)

Comment: Did you try UCS-2 (effectively UTF-16) instead?

Comment: you mean `encodeAsUcs2` for `phone` and `mesage` or all `cmd`?

Comment: As far as I know, SMS supports GSM-7 (8-bit encoding) and UTF-16 (16-bit encoding; previously UCS-2) only, whereas UTF-8 is a variable character length encoding that cannot be used there. I would start with the message body first, but I didn't work with SMS at that low level, so I can only guess.

Comment: Hm, I may be wrong, but the whole `cmd` should probably be converted (I mean, what's the point of mixing encodings otherwise?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've an example project of GSM device communication in Java which I run in a raspberry attached to a SIMCom800L module. It uses jSerialComm for serial communications which works nice with no configuration at all. Please take a look to my repo: https://github.com/pepevalbe/sms-gateway

To send Unicode you need to configure your GSM device **Character Set**. Check possible sets with this command:

```
AT+CSCS=?
+CSCS: ("GSM","UCS2","IRA","HEX")
```

If the answer contains "HEX" or "UCS2", Unicode seems to be supported. I tried with UCS2 and it is working nice. Just change the **Character Set** with: `AT+CSCS="UCS2"` This will only affect to sms, not regular commands.

Now your device will properly recognize the unicode strings you send from Java. Don't forget to set the sms text mode as well: `AT+CMGF=1`

I give you a full example based on my repo:

```
//SIMCom serial port configuration: 115200 bps, 8 bit data, no parity, 1 bit stop, no data stream control
SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("serial0");
serialPort.setComPortParameters(115200, 8, ONE_STOP_BIT, NO_PARITY);
serialPort.setFlowControl(FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLED);
serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 3000, 0);
serialPort.openPort();

// Set sms text mode
String textModeCommand = "AT+CMGF=1\r";
serialPort.writeBytes(textModeCommand.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), textModeCommand.length());

// Set UCS2 charset
String characterSetCommand = "AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"\r";
serialPort.writeBytes(characterSetCommand.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), characterSetCommand.length());

// Send sms command
String sendTextCommand1 = "AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\n";
String sendTextCommand2 = text + (char) 26 + "\r";
serialPort.writeBytes(sendTextCommand1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), sendTextCommand1.length());
serialPort.writeBytes(sendTextCommand2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16), sendTextCommand2.length());
```

Notice that in the send sms command **I encoded the text part using UTF_16 charset**, not UTF_8

Comment: Call `AT+CSCS=?` and I got `+CSCS: ("GSM","PCCP437","CUSTOM","HEX")`, cannot set `AT+CSCS="UCS2"`

Comment: Go for HEX then. You need to encode the text string as hexadecimal. Check this out: https://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/

Comment: I think I have the wrong config or something, I sent `06450631062D06280627 <CTRL-Z>` like your example but got `ùEù1ù-ù(ù'` instead of  `مرحبا`

Comment: I missing `AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8 <ENTER>`

Answer (score 1):

To send unicode text ,first the charset to be selected as UTF-16 (UCS2)

AT+CSCS="UCS2"

After you set  AT+CSCS="UCS2" every single string parameter you send must be encoded to UCS2 format ,

You canrefer the blow utilty to enCode to UCS2
http://d-chips.blogspot.com/2012/06/coding-of-alpha-fields-in-sim-for-ucs2.html

Answer (score 0):

Following are the reasons need to be check in sending/receiving unicoded text

- Make sure your reading the input in UTF-8 format, create InputstreamReader constructor with UTF-8 encoding

> InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =  new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**For more references** : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

- Use bytemessage methods instead of text message for sending/receiving unicode text

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html